# Strange 'index.php' Issue

Tags: url, siteurl

I have built and deployed dozens of Craft sites, so I know how to remove 'index.php' from urls, but now I have a site that refuses to accept my most determined efforts to remove it.

This is the situation:

- I am using the Craft supplied .htaccess file with the same settings
  as all of my other sites.
- Just to be thorough, I added 'omitScriptNameInUrls' => 'true', to the config file
- double checked all of the general settings in the CP and all is as it should be

After trying a few things, I found that if I use {{ siteUrl }}*path* I get a clean url, but if I use {{ url('path') }} it leaves that nasty index.php in the url. The same is true for {{ entry.url }}. One last bit of puzzlement - if I manually enter a full path, e.g. http://sitename/news it works fine

I suspect I am missing something obvious, but it is definitely driving me nuts!

Answer (score 4):

This recently tripped me up. `'true'` (with quotes) is not the same as `true` (without the quotes).

Lose the quotes in the config file, clear Craft's caches, and it should stick.

Also make sure your `siteUrl` is the same as what your web server is configured as. If you have a redirect in there, say `www.example.com` goes to `example.com`, and your `siteUrl` is configured to use the former, that seems to trip up Craft's check too.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! I knew it was something stupid on my part, guess I need to take more frequent breaks.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Mark it correct if you'd like. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried everything here? https://craftcms.com/support/remove-index.php

Comment: Yes - as I said, doing this is nothing new for me